# zap is not installing

Tags: java, zap

i dont know why its not installing i dont know what to do [error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WI2L8.png)
its showing this i did instal java 64 bit jre its not working please hele me

i tride to delete and install again it did'nt work

i delete it many times and install

still its not installing zap its showing the same thing locate java 64 bit file

i also tride to locate the file it did'nt work but i dont know where the file is if i know where the file is its not selecting the file

Comment: Which Java 64 bit JRE have you installed?

Comment: https://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp

Comment: That's Java 8, ZAP 2.12 requires Java 11. As noted on the download page, release notes, help, getting started guide, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message:

1. You didn't install a JRE >= Java 11.
2. You installed a 32bit JRE.
3. Your JRE can't be found. (If you're using Adopt OpenJDK or Temurin, etc. [I can't think of all of them.] there's an option to set JAVA_HOME and JavaSoft registry keys, you should enable those. Plus may need to reboot before installing [thanks Windows ‍♂️].)

Comment: I am downloading the 64 bit one

Comment: Which JRE? 7? 11?

Answer (score 0):

For everybody that do not want to help, you should really read between the lines

The application says it needs atleast JRE 11, what it doesn't tell you is that it actually needs atleast ***JDK 11***. So if you install regular java, you will not get that requirement set because it is not the same as the development kit, which is what it needs.

install the java development kit (ver 21 at the time of this writing) and you should be good: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/